# setHours() changes date for two objects when applied to one

Tags: javascript

I have a Date object and I want to create another Date object that is four hours later. I wrote the following code

```
eventStart = new Date();

eventEnd = eventStart;
eventEnd.setHours(eventEnd.getHours() + 4);

console.log(eventStart);
console.log(eventEnd);
```

both console.logs give the same date four hours later?

Why does setHours applies to both date objects here? And is there a workaround?

Also see the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AT3K2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
eventEnd = eventStart;
```

you set the value of `eventEnd` to be **the same** than `eventStart`, that is a **reference** to the same object. That is, you don't have two objects, you have **one** object and two references to it:

```
+---------------------+
| eventStart variable |---\
+---------------------+   |    +------------------------+
                          +--->| the actual Date object |
+---------------------+   |    +------------------------+
| eventEnd variable   |---/
+---------------------+
```

To create a new object whose life will be independant, do this :

```
eventEnd = new Date(eventStart.getTime());
```

This operation is commonly known as cloning.

Comment: Correct, worth mentioning to OP - unlike other languages JS dates are not immutable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Many coders here know a language where the standard Date API is similar and shitty too... you know that language which is to JavaScript as car is to cargo...

Comment: Is this only for the date api? Or does this also apply for other objects?

Comment: @Bunker You have the same "problem" with all objects : the value of a variable is a *reference* to the object so when you pass that value, you pass a reference to the same object.